# Can you use auto-increment in MySql with out it being the primary Key

Tags: sql, mysql, nhibernate, primary-key, auto-increment

I am using GUIDs as my primary key for all my other tables, but I have a requirement that needs to have an incrementing number.  I tried to create a field in the table with the auto increment but MySql complained that it needed to be the primary key.

My application uses MySql 5, nhibernate as the ORM.

Possible solutions I have thought of are:

- change the primary key to the auto-increment field but still have the Id as a GUID so the rest of my app is consistent.
- create a composite key with both the GUID and the auto-increment field.

My thoughts at the moment are leaning towards the composite key idea.

EDIT: The Row ID (Primary Key) is the GUID currently.  I would like to add an an INT Field that is Auto Incremented so that it is human readable.  I just didn't want to move away from current standard in the app of having GUID's as primary-keys.

Comment: Does the incrementing number have to be incremented by the database or could it be calculated from the code?

Comment: There is now reason for it not to be calculated from code.  With it being a web app I wasn't thinking that it would be possible from code and still ensure uniqueness.  Happy to be proven wrong though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A GUID value is intended to be unique across tables and even databases so, make the auto_increment column primary index and make a UNIQUE index for the GUID

Answer (score 5):

I would lean the other way.

Why?  Because creating a composite key gives the impression to the next guy who comes along that it's OK to have the same GUID in the table twice but with different sequence numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`GUID`'s are not intended to be orderable, that's why `AUTO_INCREMENT` for them does not make sense.

You may, though, use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` for a second column of a composite primary key in `MyISAM` tables. You can create a composite key over `(GUID, INT)` column and make the second column to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

To generate a new `GUID`, just call `UUID()` in an `INSERT` statement or in a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

- If your GUID is auntoincremental and unique, why not let it be the actual Primary Key?
- On the other hand, you should never take semantical decisions based on programmatic problems: you have a problem with MySQL, not with the design of your DB.

So, a couple of workarounds here:

- Creating a trigger that would set the GUID to the proper value once it's inserted. That's a MySQL solution to a MySQL problem, without altering semantics for your schema.
- Before inserting, start a transaction (make sure auto commit is set to false), find out the latest GUID, increment and insert with the new value. In other words, auto-increment not automatically :P

Comment: GUIDs are not autoincremental.  they're like UUIDs, a semi-random very long number so it's extremely unlikely to collide anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I know GUIDs are long numbers, but he asked for they being autoincremental, so that's what I answered :)

Answer (score 0):

No, only the primary key can have auto_increment as its value.

Comment: Wrong. Any key in MySQL can have auto_increment. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: @defines I can't find the information you mention in the link you provided. Only related thing is 'For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index.'

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you can't change the identity column to be a primary key, what about manually generating the auto-increment via some kind of SEQUENCE table plus a trigger to query the SEQUENCE table and save the next value to use. Then assign the value to the destination table in the trigger. Same effect. The only question I would have is whether the auto-incremented value is going to make it back thru NHibernate without a re-select of the table.