# how to make one coulmn as auto increment other can primary key in the same table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a table named as **tbl_bank**, in that i have created 4 columns as `id,acc_name,acc_type,bank_name`.

I need `id` as **autoincrement** and `acc_name` as **primary key**. What is the solution?

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151314/i-need-to-auto-increment-a-field-in-mysql-that-is-not-primary-key

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634231/can-you-use-auto-increment-in-mysql-with-out-it-being-the-primary-key

Comment: Is there a reason why using `unique` for `acc_name` would not work for you. Also why do you have `id` as autoincr when you don't want to use it as primary?

Answer (score 1):

***you should try this:***

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_bank` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `acc_name` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `acc_type` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `bank_name` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`acc_name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: The op only wants to have `acc_name` as primary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Acc_name varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
acc_type varchar(255),
bank_name varchar(255),
UNIQUE KEY id (id)
)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95b52fe)

Answer (score 0):

create table tbl_bank(
id int unique auto_increment,
acc_name varchar(20) not null primary key,
acc_type varchar(10),
bank_name varchar(20));

for further query visit [kuchhbhiii.blogspot.in](http://kuchhbhiii.blogspot.in)

Answer (score -1):

While creating table, use following
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT